# Compiling vala with cmake: `Undefined reference to 'g_thread_init'`

Tags: cmake, vala

I am pretty new to vala and I am trying to build something with CMAKE. However, near the end it throws `undefined reference to 'g_thread_init'`. I have added `--thread` to `OPTIONS` part of ValaPrecompile. I have also tried to add `pkg_check_modules(DEPS REQUIRED gthread-2.0)` and `add_definitions(${CFLAGS} -lgthread-2.0 )` but no luck.

Output of `pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0` :

```
-pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a guess, have you tried moving `-pthread` after `-lgthread-2.0`?

Answer (score 4):

There may be other solutions, but what I ended up doing for this very same problem was the following:

```
target_link_libraries(myTarget ${LIBRARIES} gthread-2.0)
```

Where myTarget is your target binary and LIBRARIES is your list of other libraries.